# Codeigniter : how to create dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i tried to create a dynamic dropdown in the form page, while user filling the form, there will be a dynamic dropdown for user to select a certain/specific thing, once it's selected, it can be saved into the database. But when i testing it, the dynamic dropdown show nothing, how can i fix it??

The model :

```
public function get_jenis_pekerjaan(){
        $query = $this->db->get('jenis_pekerjaan');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

The Controller :

```
public function job_type(){
        $data['jenis_pekerjaan'] = $this->m_lowongan->get_jenis_pekerjaan();
        $this->load->view('create_lowongan', $data);
    }

    public function store_lowongan(){
        $user_name          = $this->session->userdata('name');
        $title              = $this->input->post('title');
        $lokasi             = $this->input->post('lokasi');
        $level_pekerja      = $this->input->post('jenis_pekerjaan');
        $pengalaman_kerja   = $this->input->post('pengalaman_kerja');
        $pendidikan         = $this->input->post('pendidikan');
        $alamat             = $this->input->post('alamat');
        $no_wa              = $this->input->post('no_wa');
        $no_telp            = $this->input->post('no_telp');
        $min_gaji           = $this->input->post('min_gaji');
        $max_gaji           = $this->input->post('max_gaji');
        $job_desc           = $this->input->post('job_desc');
        $created_at         = date('y-m-d');
        $status             = 'draft';

        $data = array(
            'user_name'         => $user_name,
            'title'             => $title,
            'lokasi'            => $lokasi,
            'level_pekerja'     => $level_pekerja,
            'pengalaman_kerja'  => $pengalaman_kerja,
            'pendidikan'        => $pendidikan,
            'alamat'            => $alamat,
            'no_wa'             => $no_wa,
            'no_telp'           => $no_telp,
            'min_gaji'          => $min_gaji,
            'max_gaji'          => $max_gaji,
            'job_desc'          => $job_desc,
            'created_at'        => $created_at,
            'status'            => $status,
        );

        $this->m_lowongan->input_data($data, 'lowongan');
        redirect ('dashboard');
    }
```

The view :

```
<tr>
                            <td>Level Pekerjaan</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="jenis_pekerjaan" id="jenis_pekerjaan" class="form-control">
                                  <?php foreach($jenis_pekerjaan as $l) {?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $l['jenis_pekerjaan']?>"><?php echo $l['jenis_pekerjaan']?></option>
                                  <?php }?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check what `$jenis_pekerjaan` contains?

Comment: It should be containing the data from ```jenis_pekerjaan``` table. ```jenis_pekerjaan``` table contains
```
id     job_type
1 =>full time
2 => part time
3 => contract
```

Comment: It should or it does?

Comment: It does contain the value from ```jenis_pekerjaan``` table

Comment: And what **exaclty** is not working then? Are the options printed to the markup?

Comment: The option is not shown, when the dynamic dropdown is created, and i click on it, it shows nothing

Comment: There is never any need to declare the `value` attribute of an option take if the value will be identical to the option's text. It is not clear why your 2d array  doesn't work, but your object array does.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it work by doing this.

1. I create a function to get the data in the model:

```php
public function get_jenis_pekerjaan(){
    return $this->db->get('jenis_pekerjaan');
}
```

2. I call that function into my controller:

```php
public function create_lowongan() {
    $data['jenis_pekerjaan'] = $this->m_lowongan->get_jenis_pekerjaan()->result();
    $this->load->view('create_lowongan', $data);
}
```

3. I add the `$data_jp` in my store function to store the value of `jenis_pekerjaan`:

```php
public function store_lowongan() {
    $data_jp['jenis_pekerjaan'] = $this->m_lowongan->get_jenis_pekerjaan();
    $user_name          = $this->session->userdata('name');
    $title              = $this->input->post('title');
    $lokasi             = $this->input->post('lokasi');
    $level_pekerja      = $this->input->post('jenis_pekerjaan');
    $pengalaman_kerja   = $this->input->post('pengalaman_kerja');
    $pendidikan         = $this->input->post('pendidikan');
    $alamat             = $this->input->post('alamat');
    $no_wa              = $this->input->post('no_wa');
    $no_telp            = $this->input->post('no_telp');
    $min_gaji           = $this->input->post('min_gaji');
    $max_gaji           = $this->input->post('max_gaji');
    $job_desc           = $this->input->post('job_desc');
    $created_at         = date('y-m-d');
    $status             = 'draft';

    $data = array(
        'user_name'         => $user_name,
        'title'             => $title,
        'lokasi'            => $lokasi,
        'level_pekerja'     => $level_pekerja,
        'pengalaman_kerja'  => $pengalaman_kerja,
        'pendidikan'        => $pendidikan,
        'alamat'            => $alamat,
        'no_wa'             => $no_wa,
        'no_telp'           => $no_telp,
        'min_gaji'          => $min_gaji,
        'max_gaji'          => $max_gaji,
        'job_desc'          => $job_desc,
        'created_at'        => $created_at,
        'status'            => $status,
    );

    $this->m_lowongan->input_data($data, 'lowongan');
    redirect ('dashboard');
}
```

4. I edit the view so it looks like this for the dynamic dropdown:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Level Pekerjaan</td>
    <td>
        <select name="jenis_pekerjaan" id="jenis_pekerjaan" class="form-control">
            <?php foreach($jenis_pekerjaan as $l) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $l->job_type?>"><?php echo $l->job_type?></option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And it work, it show the value from `jenis_pekerjaan` table, and it store the data into the database :D